# Use SNMP and Access point wifi

Tags: wifi, snmp

I am not an expert of the network domain.

Today I have a network with a connection to the Internet. Some computers use an ethernet connection, others use the WIFI.

I wish to monitor the network because we have a slow connection.

I plan to add a switch with SNMP in front of my modem.

If I connect an access point wifi on the switch, would I be able to differentiate the different computers connected in wifi ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any network equipment that has the BRIDGE-MIB [RFC 1493](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1493) implemented will let you check which port is doing what on your network. You would want a switch/router that is also an access point, or if separate equipment, then the access point needs the BRIDGE-MIB.